# Excel VBA Macro to refresh UDF's without making them Volatile

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of different UDF in my spreadsheet (Which are not volatile), I'm wonder if it is possible to have another UDF that's called "Refresh" which will refresh all UDF used on the sheet?

I don't wish to make any of my UDF volitle due to the amount of data involved but having a button that can refresh them would solve my issue, any help/code would be appreciated.

Here is the UDF:

```
Function HexCode(cell As Range) As String 
     HexCode = Right("000000" & Hex(cell.Interior.Color), 6) 
End Function
```

Comment: wouldn't .cells.recalculate work?

Comment: strangeley no it doesn't,

Comment: can you try Ctrl+Shift+F9 and see if that does it?

Comment: Does Nothing if it help here my code `Function HexCode(cell As Range) As String
    HexCode = Right("000000" & Hex(cell.Interior.Color), 6)
End Function`

Comment: Sorry, was a bit too early when I started.  In a button, this seems to work for me: Cells.Calculate.  If that's not working for you, then there may be something else going on

Answer (score 1):

Identify the cells containing your UDF and recalculate them? That's easy: just use the RefreshUDF() macro below.

Refresh those cells from a function, recalculated on the sheet as part of the sheet's 'calculation tree'?  **Verboten!**

I've coded RefreshUDF as a subroutine because Excel won't let you do that: functions in cells cannot change other cells' values by any method other than passing the cell's own value into the dependency chain of the calculation tree.

...Except that you can capture the WorksheetChange() event and use it to read a target cell and run RefreshUDF. Take care with that, you might find it runs repeatedly (or, worse, that there's a loop) if you're changing a 'precedent' cell feeding values into the target cell.

The code below will be slow: there are several optimisations available, starting with setting calculation to manual, so that each cell refresh doesn't recalculate the entire sheet;  but it'll get you started:

```
Public Sub RefreshUDF(UDFname as string, Optional wsh as Excel.Worksheet)  

Dim myCell As Excel.Range  


If wsh Is Nothing Then 
    Set wsh = ActiveSheet
End If 

For Each myCell In wsh.UsedRange 
    If IsError(myCell) Then
        ' No action
    Else
        If Instr(1, myCell.Formula, UDFname & "(", vbTextCompare) Then
            myCell.Calculate
        End If
    End If
Next myCell 

End Sub
```

Obvious points:

Firstly, you might have another function that has a very similar name - 'ExtendedHexCode' instead of 'HexCode' - and this function will recalculate them both.

Secondly, this won't handle merged cells and array formulae well.

Thirdly, if you really are interested in the interior colour of the cell, you might be surprised to hear that this property is unchanged by conditional formatting - the cell changes colour, but the Format Condition's displayed colour isn't the same property as Interior.Color.

Also: I have to ask - have you looked up `Application.Volatile = False` ?  That should be the first line of your function... And you might find that cells with conditional formatting are volatile, no matter what you do.

Comment: the idea of having it not volatile and refreshing it with a UDF macro was for calculation speed more than anything. I will mark this as the answer for the question as you have explained it well for any other users asking the same question but I will have to think how I want to pursue this for my own application. Thanks

Comment: Always a pleasure. It may well be that your solution involves moving your calculated data into a single block, loading that block into a VBA in a single 'hit' to the sheet, and updating a 'results' block with an output array - again, in a single 'hit', it's *way* faster than cell-by-cell updates... But we're now moving away from Excel-for-calculations and into 'Excel-as-a-display-interface' with the calculations performed elsewhere.